# Are there any graph/plotting/anything-like-that libraries for Python 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, graphing, scatter-plot

As per the title. I am trying to create a simple scater plot, but haven't found any Python 3.0 libraries that can do it. Note, this isn't for a website, so the web ones are a bit useless.

Comment: I'm sure I'll get modded down for this but, why do you need to use python 3 to make a graph?

Comment: Because the program that creates the data is written in Python 3?

Comment: If you can run 2.6 on the same platform, then you can do the graphing in 2.6 from data generated in 3.0.

Comment: @S.Lott: Yeah, I'm looking into that too. I think that's what I'm going to have to end up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Python Imaging Library (PIL).
Also have a look at PyX, but this library is meant to output to PDF, ...

Answer (score 1):

The GChartWrapper (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GChartWrapper/0.7) does work for py3k

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Google Chart Wrapper?

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GChartWrapper/0.7

Comment: Sorry, should have said that it wasn't for a website. I've still bookmarked it though, it looks quite good.

Comment: But you have the option to download the image. It may not be for a website, but if you have internet access, Google Chart still works.

Answer (score 0):

I would call [Gnuplot](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net) from Python. No need to reinvent the wheel in Python, Gnuplot is already there and already has a Python interface.

Comment: It requires NumPy, which isn't 3.0 compatible.

Comment: you can pipe shell commands to Gnuplot from Python and pass it a data file.  So it would be possible without Numpy (though uglier)

Comment: Actually, numpy has been 3.0 compatible for quite awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

The current [development version of matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) should work on Python 3.